# What is a good Data Structure for the following type of data representation?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I am trying to store frame by frame voxel information for a mesh. That is in each frame, I am trying to store what primitives each voxels will contain. Everything will be just integer keys so essentially its a table like this :

```
FRAME 1
Voxel 1 : { 3,4,5 }
Voxel 2 : { 7,8 }
Voxel 3 : NULL
..
..
Voxel 5000 : {1223,43,42}

FRAME 2
Voxel 1 : { 3,5 }
Voxel 2 : { 7,8,0 }
Voxel 3 : NULL
..
..
Voxel 5000 : {123,413,422}

...
```

What will be the best way to store this ? At this point, I am thinking of something like

> std::vector < std::vector< std::list  > >

That is the outer vector will contain the frame by frame data. The inner vector will contain the per voxel list data.

Is this OK or is there a better templete DS I can use?

Comment: I can see even a 3D jagged array being pretty slow, let alone a 2D jagged array of linked lists. I'll bet you'd see a significant speed increase with the flattening of at least one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

1. List of frames.

   ```
   std::vector<Frame> frames;
   ```
2. Frame = list of Voxels.

   ```
   typedef std::vector<Voxel> Frame;
   ```
3. Voxel = list of `int`s.

   ```
   typedef std::vector<int> Voxel;
   ```

Reverse the order of declaration to use them.

```
typedef std::vector<int> Voxel;
typedef std::vector<Voxel> Frame;
std::vector<Frame> frames;
```

Answer (score 1):

**"What will be the best way to store this?".**

There is no single right answer to your question.  You've picked a very reasonable data structure given your description of the data being stored.

If you have a particular optimization objective (e.g. minimize execution time, minimize memory usage), then a different data structure may be more effective at achieving your goal.